# Mac VNC and Windows Remote Desktop License Issue

Tags: windows-7, macos, remote-desktop, vnc

I am trying to connect a Windows 7 machine to Mac using Windows Remote Desktop Client. It works and shows MAC login screen but when I try to login using a username and password it gives me following error. I know the the user "temp" works on Mac itself but not on Windows using remote desktop.

> The remote session was disconnected
>   because there are no Remote Desktop
>   client access licenses available for
>   this computer. Please contact the
>   server administrator.

I have checked Remote Login and Remote Management in MAC to yes but is there something missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use Vine VNC on the mac and then use your favorite flavor of VNC client on the Windows machine?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/

Comment: I want to give it a try

Comment: OK It just shows the same dialog having licence issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. It sounds counterintuitive, but try it. On the Mac, go to the Apple and select System Preferences. In the Internet and Wireless section click Sharing. Turn off Remote Login and Remote Management. (Uncheck the checkboxes.) When you do this, another option displays: "Allow access for:". Select the "All users" radio button. That's it! You can quit System Preferences and successfully RDP from Windows to the Mac.